# Openshift, accessing a web service: AxisFault: Permission denied

Tags: tomcat, openshift

I have created a Tomcat app in Openshift, I deployed multiple war files in web app folder, it was successfully deployed. The problem when accessing this web services from another web application (JSP file) wrapped in war file, I got these errors. Any help!

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Permission denied
    org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:197)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:404)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:231)
    org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:443)
    org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:406)
    org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    org.tempuri.CarRentalServerStub.getCars(CarRentalServerStub.java:8314)
    sir.master.project.TravelInvocation.carCall(TravelInvocation.java:153)
    org.apache.jsp.TravelSearch_jsp._jspService(TravelSearch_jsp.java:444)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: It looks like a Permission Denied during an HTTP request, which usually points to you trying to bind to the incorrect IP address. By default, java tends to use 0.0.0.0, which is disallowed in OpenShift. Instead, you should bind to the value of $OPENSHIFT_[APP_NAME]_IP. For a jbossews app, this would be $OPENSHIFT_JBOSSEWS_IP